# DoubleAnimation with "instant" change not smooth transition

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm using the following animation to "flash" a control:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
    From="1"
    To="0.3"
    AutoReverse="True"
    Duration="0:0:0.5"
    RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
```

The resulting effect is more like a fade in and out. What I'm really after is to just "flip" the opacity from one value to the other (and back) every 0.5 seconds, rather than a smooth transition. How do I achieve that?

Comment: `DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame` is what you're after (ref [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744833(v=vs.110).aspx), XAML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution you are looking for:

```
<Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:0.5" AutoReverse="True">
       <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
              <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="0.3" KeyTime="0:0:0.25" />
       </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

You can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Discrete flashing (blinking), alternating between two values -- added this comment to make this more findable.